# Problem with sound and touchpad in UBnutu

Tags: drivers, sound, touchpad

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 in my ASUS ROG G18 laptop, however my touchpad isn't working,  especially i couldn't hear any sound from my laptop though i checked every possible settings